# Reportlab and PIL : unpack requires a string argument of length 1 Imaging Library not available, unable to import bitmaps only jpegs

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I've an issue using ReportLab abd PIL (in Flask project), using Vagrant's VM (2.2.3)

The error is located using the *readJPEGInfo()* function. The PNG file (*-rwxrwxr-- 1 www-data www-data 21K juin  22  2018*) is there :

```
site_media/img/84/5_1_pied_de_page.png: PNG image data, 1066 x 47, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

The error message :

```
(unpack requires a string argument of length 1 Imaging Library not available, unable to import bitmaps only jpegs 
fileName='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/20/5_1_pied_de_page.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7fdd75f2a110 
filename='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/20/5_1_pied_de_page.png'] 
fileName='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/20/5_1_pied_de_page.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7fdd75f2a110 
filename='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/20/5_1_pied_de_page.png'] --> <class 'struct.error'> => Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/www/my_project/my_project/flask_my_project/views.py", line 206, in zonesmeteo createDisplay(t, config, tabAlerts, demain, message)

File "/var/www/my_project/my_project/flask_my_project/utils.py", line 29, in createDisplay tr.generateFiles() 
File "/var/www/my_project/my_project/cron_dept_treatments/84.py", line 64, in generateFiles self.dicoFolders) 
File "/var/www/my_project/my_project/cron_dept_treatments/84.py", line 258, in __init__ table5.drawOn(self.c,15,12) 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 111, in drawOn self._drawOn(canvas)
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 92, in _drawOn self.draw()#this is the bit you overload 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/tables.py", line 1425, in draw self._drawCell(cellval, cellstyle, (colpos, rowpos), (colwidth, rowheight)) 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/tables.py", line 1558, in _drawCell v.drawOn(self.canv,x,y) 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 111, in drawOn self._drawOn(canvas)
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 92, in _drawOn self.draw()#this is the bit you overload 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 511, in draw self.canv.drawImage( self._img or self.filename, 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 481, in __getattr__ self._img = ImageReader(self._file) 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 810, in __init__ annotateException('\nfileName=%r identity=%s'%(fileName,self.identity())) 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 1390, in annotateException rl_reraise(t,v,b) 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 804, in __init__ annotateException('\nImaging Library not available, unable to import bitmaps only jpegs\nfileName=%r identity=%s'%(fileName,self.identity())) 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 1390, in annotateException rl_reraise(t,v,b) 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 802, in __init__ self._width,self._height,c=readJPEGInfo(self.fp) 
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfutils.py", line 243, in readJPEGInfo x = struct.unpack('B', image.read(1)) error: unpack requires a string argument of length 1 Imaging Library not available, unable to import bitmaps only jpegs fileName='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/20/5_1_pied_de_page.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7fdd75f2a110 

filename='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/20/5_1_pied_de_page.png'] fileName='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/20/5_1_pied_de_page.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7fdd75f2a110
filename='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/20/5_1_pied_de_page.png'] )
```

The part of pip freeze (python 2.7 ):

```
Pillow==2.6.1
reportlab==3.4.0
```

The user/group :

```
$ cat /etc/group | grep data
www-data:x:33:vagrant,apache,nginx,httpd,www-data,www-user
```

So, I've do a simple python test file :

```
import reportlab, PIL
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import Frame, Image

png_file = "/var/www/test/5_1_pied_de_page.png"
img=canvas.Canvas(png_file)

my_doc = SimpleDocTemplate('myfile.pdf')

parts=[]
parts.append(Image(png_file))

my_doc.build(parts)
```

Same errors :

```
 File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 802, in __init__
    self._width,self._height,c=readJPEGInfo(self.fp)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfutils.py", line 243, in readJPEGInfo
    x = struct.unpack('B', image.read(1))
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 1
Imaging Library not available, unable to import bitmaps only jpegs
fileName='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/84/5_1_pied_de_page.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7fc9223f3e50 filename='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/84/5_1_pied_de_page.png']
fileName='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/84/5_1_pied_de_page.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7fc9223f3e50 filename='/var/www/my_project/my_project/site_media/img/84/5_1_pied_de_page.png']
(my_project)
```

And, in my test file, I've convert the PNG in JPG :  No error, but the pdf file is blank :)

Thanks.

F.

```
$ uname -a 
Linux vm 4.4.0-131-generic #157-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 12 15:51:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to get it into a Reportlab flowable object. Even if I would not use PIL directly in this case, I can share how I get it to work (here with a frame, but works also without). It works on most pic formats, incl png, pls note I have not tested the code below.

```
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.platypus import Image, Frame, PageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate

png_file = "/var/www/test/5_1_pied_de_page.png"

picture_frame = Frame(
    x1              =10 * cm,    # From left
    y1              =26 * cm,    # From bottom
    height          =9 * cm,
    width           =9 * cm)

frontpage = PageTemplate(id='FrontPage', onPage='', frames=[picture_frame])

picture = Image(png_file, 9 * cm, 6 * cm, hAlign='RIGHT')

my_doc = BaseDocTemplate('myfile.pdf', pagesize=A4)
my_doc.addPageTemplates(frontpage)

parts = []
parts.append(picture)

my_doc.build(parts)
```